# Query database connection from another Node.js module

Tags: node.js

Dumb question...  I am working (i.e. learning) with an API in Node.js and connecting to MongoDB using the code below.  Everything works great while the database code is located inside my routes.js file, but I would really like to move that code block out to a separate dbconfig.js file/module.

I've tried every method I can find, but the db variable/object always returns undefined when called inside my getQuery function.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!

**dbconfig.js**

```
module.exports=function() {

    var db;

    var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var mongoUrl = 'mongodb://username:password@ds123456.mongolab.com:123456/mydb';
    var mongoOptions = {
        server: {auto_reconnect: true}
    };

    getDb();

    return {
        db: this.db
    };

    function getDb() {
    mongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, mongoOptions, function(error, database) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                db = database;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**routes.js** (Relevant portion)

```
(function(routes) {
    var dbconfig = require('.\dbconfig')();
    var breezeMongo = require('breeze-mongodb');

    var db = dbconfig.db;

    function getQuery(request, result, next) {
        try { 
            var resource = request.params.resource;
            var collectionName = getCollectionName(resource);
            var query = new breezeMongo.MongoQuery(request.query);
            query.execute(db, collectionName, processResults(result, next));
        } catch (ex) {
            var err = {
                statusCode: 404,
                message: 'Unable to execute query " ' + request.url + '"',
                error: ex
            };
        }

    }

})(module.exports);
```

Comment: Did you make sure you're waiting for the connection to be made before using it? (doesn't look like it)

Comment: Also, you never set `this.db` equal to the var you defined as `db`.